# Subset of changes from transaction sometimes not visible shortly after commit

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-integration

Let's consider the following context:

2 spring integration channels, they are each in separate database transactions. At the end of the first transaction, a message is put into the second channel. In the first channel, elements are created in the database that is later consumed by the corresponding message that has been sent from the first channel to the second channel.

To make sure that the transaction from channel 1 is fully committed before the second channel is triggered our subclass of the `JpaTransactionManager` is registering a `TransactionSynchronization` in the `prepareForCommit` method it overrides from the `JpaTransactionManager`

The flow (channel 1) looks like this:

- Do all the message processing and database handling
- Last step of the flow registers a `TransactionSynchronization` that does a `MessageChannel.send` in the `afterCommit` phase to send the message to channel 2

My understanding is that at the time the message is sent to the second channel (in `afterCommit`) all changes that have been done in the database transaction of channel 1 are flushed and committed.

Now the second channel does some work (like an MQ PUT) and later updates an entry that was created in the first flow. We have now observed that the repository method returned no entry in the database, but it is visible in the table at a later point. Other entries that were also created in the transaction of the first channel however are visible. This happens only once every few thousand messages, normally they are there but sometimes they are not visible for the second channel a few milliseconds after the transaction has been committed by channel 1.

I have created an image that should illustrate it:
[image]

The `Chain 1` is the first chain that consists of multiple `ServiceActivators` that perform database work, a splitter that generates more messages and then another `ServiceActivator` that I named `SENDER` which registers the `TransactionSynchronization` that (so my understanding) should send the for example 3 generated messages to chain 2 after the red transaction is fully committed and therefore before the blue transaction begins.

One thing I have noticed is that the entries that were sometimes present and sometimes not are all in the one method that (not on purpose) uses `javax.transaction.Transactional` instead of `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`. However, we are using **spring core 5.0.8.RELEASE** and in other questions I have seen that this should make 0 difference since spring 4.2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `afterCommit` is the right place to send messages downstream.

There should be just enough to have a Service Activator for POJO method marked with the `@Transactional`. This way a transaction is going to start and finish exactly around this method call. The result of the method is going to be sent to the output channel already, exactly after that transaction is committed.

**UPDATE**

The best way to achieve your requirements is a `<gateway>` around your Chain1. This way the TX is going to be committed over there before producing reply to the Chain2 from the gateway.

With the `TransactionSynchronization::afterCommit` there is no guarantee that TX is going to be committed on DB when QueueChannel is ready for polling messages. Although you can use `JdbcChannelMessageStore` for transactional storage of messages. This way they are not going to be visible until TX commit in DB.

See more about `<gateway>` in Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#_calling_a_chain_from_within_a_chain

Comment: Will the `MessageChannel.send` only be processed when the containing `@Transactional` method closes the transaction? From what I read in the documentation if I `send` to a `QueueChannel` this message will instantly be dispatched to that channel which means my database transaction that spans the entire chain of my flow 1 may not be committed at the time the `QueueChannel` picks up the message I have sent from flow 1. That would make things worse.

Comment: Also the core of my question is more: at the point a `TransactionSynchronization::afterCommit` is called, shouldnt the data of the transaction be fully committed and visible for all subsequent transactions? Or is the old transaction potentially not fully flushed at that point?

Comment: It is really possible that handing off to the queue channel doesn't guarantee that TX on the DB is committed. You really jump to the channel still withing a TX.

Comment: The same concern is about `TransactionSynchronization::afterCommit`: there is no guarantee that TX is really finished on remote DB. You are still withing TX process when you send. Although the main concern is really might be  just because you try to send to the `QueueChannel`. Please, reconsider your architecture do not send to the channel within that `TransactionSynchronization::afterCommit`. Not sure what is wrong following my recommendation in the answer.

Comment: I am not sure I entirely understand your answer. Do you mean that instead of sending within the `afterCommit` I should send within the `ServiceActivator` method directly? Just to avoid confusion. In that case - since the queuechannel might immediately start processing of that message - wont the risk that the transaction that spans my entire chain of the first flow not be committed be much higher? It is not just one `ServiceActivator` that does database transaction and sending to a `QueueChannel`, before there are approximately 15 other steps in the chain that need the same DB TRX.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.